# Create link with "@" symbol in facebook status with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii2

I have problem with facebook api and can't find any information.

I want create link (example @Username) in status, with Graph API.

My code:

```
$response = $facebook->api("/" . $data['pageId'] . "/feed", 'POST',
    [
        'message'     => $messageContainer['message'],
        'link'        => 'https://example.com/reviews',
        'name'        => $messageContainer['subject'],
        'description' => $messageContainer['description'],
        'picture'     => 'https://example.com/uploads/dealer/' . $messageContainer['logo'],
    ]
);

$messageContainer['message'] = 'Some text @Username';
```

but text wasn't created as link in status only as string.

May be it's impossible?

Comment: I found the following in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions

Comment: You can not tag people in normal posts made via API. At most, pages can tag other pages.

Comment: @mapek, thank you, i found this documentation too